# Naming.unbind("somename") fails against wildfly 13

Tags: java, wildfly, rmi, jmx, wildfly-13

I'm migrating an app from jboss 4.2 to wildfly 13. The app exposes EJBs, successfully migrated and these EJBs are used by some standalone clients (wrapped as services with tanuki wrapper) running on the same machine as wildfly. These standalone clients are monitored using JMX.
The startup code tries to unbind the service name in case the client crashed in an earlier run using

```
Naming.unbind("//localhost:1099/myService");
```

On normal startup (not after a crash) a

```
java.rmi.NotBoundException
```

is expected.

My issue is I get the following stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
```

port 1099 is the default "well known" port as stated by the Naming javadoc:

> The Naming class provides methods for storing and obtaining references
>   to remote objects in a remote object registry. Each method of the
>   Naming class takes as one of its arguments a name that is a
>   java.lang.String in URL format (without the scheme component) of the
>   form:
>         //host:port/name
>       where host is the host (remote or local) where the registry is located, port is the port number on which the registry accepts calls,
>   and where name is a simple string uninterpreted by the registry. Both
>   host and port are optional. If host is omitted, the host defaults to
>   the local host. If port is omitted, then the port defaults to 1099,
>   the "well-known" port that RMI's registry, rmiregistry, uses.

I also tried with wildfly management port as it uses http port upgrade, I get

```
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

with the following root cause

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:265)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:246)
```

What am I missing and/or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the rmiregistry is not started by wildfly. I was mislead by our old environment that starts rmiregistry on OS startup by init.d.

So starting the rmiregistry solved my problem.

Rmi and wildfly http upgrade feature are not related to each other since rmiregistry is an independent process.